# SqliteException: SQLite Error 1: 'no such table: Patients'. - I can not seem to fix the problem

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I am looking at how to get around this problem. I am tempted to restart from scratch. It is very annoying and I have looked everywhere online how to resolve this Can anyone please help and answer this in the most simple terms possible. I did delete my original database and hit build to create a new one, but when I try to create a basic form of information I am hitting with the errors below.

I tried to run a command line I seen someone on youtube do the update-database on the command line but it said no such thing exists

The exact error that shows up is this:

> SqliteException: SQLite Error 1: 'no such table: Patients'.

Then the red that shows up is this:

```
MS.Data.Services.PatientHutServiceDb.GetPatientByEmail(string email) in 
PatientHutServiceDb.cs
+
         return db.Patients.FirstOrDefault(e => e.EmailAddress == email);
MMS.Data.Services.PatientHutServiceDb.AddPatient(Patient u) in PatientHutServiceDb.cs
 +
        var existing = GetPatientByEmail(u.EmailAddress); //Check if user has same email 
address when creating a new user 
MMS.Web.Controllers.PatientController.Create(Patient u) in PatientController.cs
+
            svc.AddPatient(u);
lambda_method35(Closure , object , object[] )
```

I feel like I need to update the database but I am not sure how to do this.

So far the code I have is this:

```
 DbContext: 


namespace MMS.Data.Repositories
```

{
public class PatientHutDbContext : DbContext
{
public DbSet Patients { get; set; }
public DbSet Bookings { get; set; }

```
    // Could use SqlServer using connection below if installed
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder               
            /** use simple logging to log the sql commands issued by entityframework **/ 
            //.LogTo(Console.WriteLine, LogLevel.Information)
            //.EnableSensitiveDataLogging()
            .UseSqlite("Filename=Patients.db"); //Double check this !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    }

    public void Initialise() 
    {
        Database.EnsureDeleted();
        Database.EnsureCreated();
    }
}
```

}

In the `startup` I file I have:

```cs
namespace MMS.Web
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {           

            services.AddControllersWithViews();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IServiceProvider provider)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();             
                           
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            //app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When starting from scratch, start with the official docs. This tutorial should bring you up-and-running: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/overview/first-app?tabs=netcore-cli

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I did delete my original database and hit build to create a new one,
> but when I try to create a basic form of information I am hitting with
> the errors below.

Based on your description, I assume the application already installed the related EF Core packages and the context has specified which entities are included in the data model and assigned the database connection string. Then, the next step should be use the [migrations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/) to [create the database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/overview/first-app?tabs=netcore-cli#create-the-database) based on the model.

If you are using Visual Studio 2019, try to use the following command:

```
Add-Migration InitialCreate
Update-Database
```

The `Add-Migration` command scaffolds a migration to create the initial set of tables for the model.
The `Update-Database` command creates the database and applies the new migration to it.

If you are using .Net Core CLI, the command should like this:

```
dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate
dotnet ef database update
```

After the Database and DataTable create success, you could execute the query statement via your DBContext.

Answer (score 0):

Following these steps will help a lot.

1. Build your projects to see if there will be any errors that will affect the migration process.
2. Ensure that you've you have set the default project to the one you want to perform the migration commands on the Package Manager Console. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUB3Y.jpg)
3. Then run the following commands:

   `Add-Migration InitialMigration`

   `Update-Database`